# erlsrv - failed to create a service on windows

Tags: windows, shell, erlang, mnesia, yaws

was trying to create a windows service like this:

```
erlsrv add muzaaya -w "C:/Folder" -c "test erlang service" -ar "-pa .. -eval \"service:start()\""
```

i got the following error immediately:

```
erlsrv: Unable to register service with service manager.
Error: Access is denied.
```

I think am not really well conversant with how to pass arguments as well as several parameters even after reading its documentation here: **http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlsrv.html**. 


 Can some one assist with an example of how to successfully create a windows service? i would want the service to start a number of applications as it comes up and to stop those applications whenever its stopping as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this question is rather old I came across it searching for a similar answer.

The solution to this problem is to make sure you execute this command as an administrator (or launch the command windows as an administrator.)